# Linked List Exception Thrown

Tags: c++

I am new with linked lists and I am getting this error when trying to remove one of the nodes of a linked list.

```
Exception thrown: Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<char,std::allocator<char> > >::_Mysize(...) returned 0xDDDDDDF1. occurred
```

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    string song, artist;
    node* next;
};

node* add(node *head)
{
    string song, artist;

    cout << "Enter song name:" << endl;
    getline(cin, song);
    cout << "Enter artist name:" << endl;
    getline(cin, artist);
    node *new_ptr = new node;
    new_ptr->song = song;
    new_ptr->artist = artist;

    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = new_ptr;
        head->next = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        node *ptr = head;
        while (ptr->next != nullptr)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next = new_ptr;
        ptr->next->next = nullptr;
    }

    cout << "Song added." << endl;

    return head;
}

node* remove(node *head)
{
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "There are no songs." << endl;
        return head;
    }

    string song_to_remove;
    bool found = false;

    cout << "Enter song name to remove:" << endl;
    getline(cin, song_to_remove);

    if (head->song.compare(song_to_remove) == 0)
    {
        found = true;
        node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    else if(head->next != nullptr)
    {
        node *prev_ptr = head;
        node *ptr = head->next;
        while (ptr != nullptr)
        {
            if (ptr->song.compare(song_to_remove) == 0)
            {
                found = true;
                node *temp = ptr;
                prev_ptr->next = ptr->next;
                delete temp;
            }

            ptr = ptr->next;
            prev_ptr = prev_ptr->next;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        cout << "Song not found." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Song removed." << endl;
    }

    return head;
}

void print(node *head)
{
    node* ptr = head;
    if (ptr == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "There are no songs added yet." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while (ptr != nullptr)
        {
            cout << ptr->song << " by " << ptr->artist << endl;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    node *head = nullptr;
    int option;

    while (1)
    {
        cout << "Choose an option: Add a song (1), remove a song (2), or list all the songs (3)." << endl;
        cin >> option;
        cin.ignore();
        if (!(option == 1 || option == 2 || option == 3))
        {
            cout << "Must pick either 1, 2, or 3." << endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (option == 1)
        {
            head = add(head);
        }
        else if (option == 2)
        {
            head = remove(head);
        }
        else if (option == 3)
        {
            print(head);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have everything working besides the remove() function, and it only errors when I have more than 1 item in the linked list and when I try to remove a node besides the first one.

Comment: Now is the perfect time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to catch crashes like this.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the `std::string` class have overloaded the `==` operator (and the other comparison operators) so you can do e.g. `head->song == song_to_remove` to check if two strings are equal.

Comment: Really? I was told to use .compare() and not == on strings

Comment: That's only needed for Java, not C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I didn't have a `break` statement after deleting `ptr` and then was trying to assign something to `ptr`. I was trying to make it work so that if you had multiple songs with the same name it would delete all of them, but the program doesn't need to be that specific.

```
node* remove(node *head)
{
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "There are no songs." << endl;
        return head;
    }

    string song_to_remove;
    bool found = false;

    cout << "Enter song name to remove:" << endl;
    getline(cin, song_to_remove);

    if (head->song == song_to_remove)
    {
        found = true;
        node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    else if(head->next != nullptr)
    {
        node *prev_ptr = head;
        node *ptr = head->next;
        while (ptr != nullptr)
        {
            if (ptr->song == song_to_remove)
            {
                found = true;
                prev_ptr->next = ptr->next;
                delete ptr;
                break;
            }

            ptr = ptr->next;
            prev_ptr = prev_ptr->next;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        cout << "Song not found." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Song removed." << endl;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem, consider marking this answer as correct solution to help future readers with a similar problem.